# Watch out for bad edits!

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

Recently I see a lot of bad edits, and worse, I see them accepted. Examples are:

- placing code in **bold marks**, instead of `code marks`
- placing module names in `code marks`
- Formatting lists as code blocks
- Wrapping code in `<code>` tags, that does not really work here, instead of using 4 spaces
- Using `backticks` on every line of code, instead of 4 spaces at the beginning of each line
- Placing **bold** and *italics* in various parts of post, even where it is not needed
- Using `<br/>` instead of 2 newlines to break a line, leaving markup hard to read

And here I listed only examples I've seen accepted in last week or so.

**PLEASE, PLEASE DON'T ACCEPT THEM ANYMORE**

If you feel post needed re-formatting, hit "edit" instead. Leave helpful tick or not, but don't let it pass. And if post didn't need it, simply reject.

Comment: Could this be edited & featured by moderator, maybe? Just to stop current wave of these edits? Hopefully it'll be over in a week or so...

Comment: I think we need to inform the user who made an edit to that post during the review queue suppose if it is not constructive. If there is any feature for that would really helpful for us to stop doing that kind of behavior from that user.

Comment: @Bala there is no way to contact editor unless his edit is accepted. Only when it is you can ping him with @ in comment. But enough of rejected edit suggestion will trigger edit ban, and hopefully make them ask on meta what's wrong.

Comment: Molot I don't know about that ban, then it's fine!!

Comment: @Mołot How often is this actually happening?  My time on the site has been really limited the last few weeks (mainly to just handle flags), so I haven't seen this happening.  If we don't already have one, I think we can use this to make a good FAQ post about edits and reviewing edits.

Comment: @MPD A significant part of [this list](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/16454/jayendra-kainthola?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and [this list](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/20322/harshal?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), and some more I can't find easily now. A couple a day at least, I'm afraid. But I didn't post to call names, please delete this comment as soon as feasible. It's my general concern.

Comment: I am agree with @MPD that there should be a tutorial in site about edits and post formatting. So, we people also aware about correct formatting. I have checked [help](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help) in the Drupal exchange but did not find what is correct way to do formatting a post. If you have any link for the same, please share.