# User comment loading in the editor

Tags: discussion

Yesterday user post a comment to ping me in this [post](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/watch-out-for-bad-edits), but that comment still loading in the editor whenever I open that post, but that comment is deleted by the user. Looks strange and also I hard refresh the page but still appearing. Did anyone see that comment appear in your editor too ?

Note: Yesterday I think I pasted that comment in the editor in my office computer, because of that it still appearing but even I clicked the leave page and hard refresh in my home  laptop, but that comment won't leave me.

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Post drafts get saved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting), and will persist across machines.  When this happens, you will see a **Draft Saved** indicator under the edit area.

You should be able to click the discard button below the preview to get rid of the saved answer.

[image]