# Can we not add OP's comment as suggestion edit to post

Tags: discussion

After reading [this](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/watch-out-for-bad-edits?cb=1) post, I was reviewing  my suggested edit in Drupal stackexchange site and I have found suggestion edit for [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10185/how-to-write-php-warnings-and-notices-to-error-log-not-db-log-watchdog) post.

I have found that someone rejected my edit and mentioned below reason for rejection.

> Beside that it is not properly edited, the edit presumes things that
>   the OP never mentioned

While I was reading post, I found that OP added more information in comment which is related to his question.

Is this not a correct way to copy text from comment and edit post, if that comment is related to question?